# How to index multiple properties on javascript object at the same time

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, syntax

Let's say I have a JavaScript object like:

```
var x = {
  'one': 1,
  'two': 2,
  'three': 3
}
```

Then I have an array, which contains keys that I want to access from this object.

Here are my keys:

```
var keys = ['one', 'two'];
```

Now when I use these keys to pull out what I want from the object, it should look like this...

```
{
  'one': 1,
  'two': 2
}
```

My pseudo-code mind imagines the code looking like this:

```
var x = {
  'one': 1,
  'two': 2,
  'three': 3
}
var keys = ['one', 'two'];
var answer = x[keys];
```

But I know this doesn't actually work...

Is there an elegant way of doing this in javascript? Using an array to index multiple properties of an object?

I can imagine a `for-loop` version using brute force, but I'm wondering if this is a JavaScript feature I'm unaware of?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes a bit of code, but I think the closest you can get is using `Object.fromEntries` to map over the keys to a new object.

```js
var x = {
  'one': 1,
  'two': 2,
  'three': 3
};
var keys = ['one', 'two'];

const newObj = Object.fromEntries(
  keys.map(key => [key, x[key]])
);
console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: Yeah this isn't so bad I guess, I was really hoping to learn some super crazy syntax or something I'd never see before tho haha

Comment: I don't think there's a more concise way. There are libraries that implement this, of course, but that's just hiding the code that implements it under the hood.

Comment: yeah that's what I assumed... the purpose of the question wasn't really to see it done this way tho, I mostly just wanted to see if there was some syntax I was unaware of, but I'll accept this answer anyway <3

Comment: Then you have to loop 2 times? `First - keys.map`, `Second - Object.fromEntries`

Comment: `"I don't think there's a more concise way"` How about [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67040942/9071943)? @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the highest performance `O(n)` time complexity like this.

```js
var x = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3};
var keys = ['one', 'two', 'five'];

const result = keys.reduce((acc, curr) => (curr in x && (acc[curr] = x[curr]), acc), {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help ^^! @Alec Donald Mather

Comment: Small Problem: If `keys` contains some value that is not in `x`, then `result` will have that value set to `undefined`, which I guess is not generally desired. Putting a simple check would fix this: `keys.reduce((acc, curr) => (curr in x && (acc[curr] = x[curr]), acc), {})`

Comment: Yeah. That makes sense. I'm hanging ou with my friend. So feel free to edit my post to make it more general accordingly. Thank in advance @Som Shekhar Mukherjee

Comment: Hi @SomShekharMukherjee . I've just checked your update. Why did you use `curr in x &&` instead of `x[curr] &&` ? Which one is the best in terms of *performance, browser support, and clean code*?

Comment: **Performance**: I guess should be almost similar, not tested though. **Support**: Full Support, **Clean Code**: Both I would say are clean, `in` according to me is more readable, when I see `curr in x && something`, I read ok if that property exists on the object then do the rest. Do let me know what you feel, and if you have some performance insights as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want;

```js
var x = {
  'one': 1,
  'two': 2,
  'three': 3
}

var keys = ['one', 'two'];
let res = {};
keys.forEach(key => {res[key] = x[key]})
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Oops, you are using `map` for other purpose of its :)

Comment: Can you please explain. Sorry but i didn't got you..

Comment: Yes. Basically, [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) *method creates a new array*. While you just use it to iterate and assign value to `res`. You should use `forEach` instead. `keys.forEach(key => {res[key] = x[key]})`

Comment: You are right. But is there any big issue with that. What i mean is will it create any problem as it still works properly

Comment: It has side effect. Besides, Due to create a new array, it means need extra memory space to do it. That's what I mean :) You can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67040942/9071943) above if needed. Happy coding +1 ^^!